# What's the best way to calculate the average wind speed?

Tags: average

I am randomly generating wind speed for the X and Z axes. Let's say I have that the wind is blowing X MPH in the north direction and Y MPH in the east direction. I want one final value for the wind's speed, though.

Is it accurate to just say that the wind's speed is equal to (X+Y)/2? So if the north wind speed is 11 MPH and the east wind speed is 2 MPH, the overall wind speed is 6.5 MPH?

Comment: The speed is a vector. You need to do vector addition instead of scalar addition.

Comment: So then the vectors would be <x,0> and <0,y>. Adding them would equal <x,y>. Would the wind speed be equal to the magnitude of this vector then? (so 11.18 MPH in my original example?)

Comment: For 2D case, yes.

Comment: Yeah I meant the 2D case. Thanks! If you'd like to answer the question I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: No problem. You already understand it right? So I don't need to write it up again. By the way, when you define a vector, you need to define both its magnitude and its direction. In this case, the direction of the wind is northeast, with an angle of $arctan(2/11)$ away from north.